# Problems with Japanese Characters (あ, い, う, え, お) in the Gmail subject

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

We implemented a function to create drafts using [Compose Actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/compose).
However, the subject is garbled.
If the subject is `あいうえお`, it will be `Re: BDFHJ`.
I want to prevent garbled characters.

this code.

Code.js

```
function buildCard (e) {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("タイトル"));
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();
  var composeAction = CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName('createReplyDraft');
  var composeButton = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Compose Reply')
    .setComposeAction(composeAction, CardService.ComposedEmailType.REPLY_AS_DRAFT);
  section.addWidget(composeButton);
  card.addSection(section);
  return card.build();
}

/**
 *  Creates a draft email (with an attachment and inline image)
 *  as a reply to an existing message.
 *  @param {Object} e data passed by the compose action.
 *  @return {ComposeActionResponse}
 */
function createReplyDraft(e) {
  // Activate temporary Gmail add-on scopes, in this case to allow
  // a reply to be drafted.
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

  // Creates a draft reply.
  var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  var draft = message.createDraftReply('あいうえお');  //There is no problem with body.

  // Return a built draft response. This causes Gmail to present a
  // compose window to the user, pre-filled with the content specified
  // above.
  return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
    .setGmailDraft(draft).build();
}
```

appsscript.json

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Gmail Add-on Quickstart",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/2x/bookmark_black_24dp.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "buildCard"
    }],
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://mail.google.com/"
    ],
    "primaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "secondaryColor": "#4285F4"
  },
  "oauthScopes":[ 
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
}
```

this flow.

step1.
You've got mail.

[image]

step2.
Click the `Compose Reply`
[image]

step3.
Edit Subject.
[image]

step4.
Subject is garbled.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, in my environment, I couldn't replicate your situation. I can use gmail with old or new version. And I don't modify my gmail and use the default settings. For this situation, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your situation?

Comment: It seems you have declared your OAuth scopes twice...

Comment: I made a mistake that oauthScopes declared twice.
Even if you delete it, it is the same behavior.

Comment: Thank you for adding them. I could also confirm the same situation. When ``あ`` is converted to UTF-16 and the lower 2 bytes are retrieved, the value is 42. In your situation, the character code of "0042" is used and ``B`` is returned. For example, ``\u3042\u0042`` is used to the subject, ``BB`` is returned. It is considered that such conversion occurs in this case. If the character code can be set when ``createDraftReply()`` is used, the correct values might be returned. But in the current situation, it cannot be done.

Comment: This is already mentioned as an issue on Google Issue Tracker:
 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78142881 "Subject garbled when creating a draft reply if the original subject uses Japanese characters"